# How to implement Linq OrderBy method?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to understand more about linq, for example, if I want to implement a Select I will implement like this

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        yield return selector(item);
    }
}
```

where like this

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

How about OrderBy?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/02/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-45-conclusion-and-list-of-posts/). I think you'll find it very useful. Basically, Jon Skeet re-implements everything in Linq as a learning exercise. Very informative.

The second part talks about implementing [`Where`](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-2-quot-where-quot/)... and so on till parts that describes [`OrderBy`](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/05/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26b-orderby-descending-thenby-descending/).

Answer (score 1):

To follow you current implementation pattern you could try this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    var items = source.ToArray();
    var keys = items.Select(keySelector).ToArray();
    Array.Sort(keys, items);
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid implementation of `OrderBy`.  You cannot call `ThenBy` on this.

Comment: @Servy - I did say that I was following the OP's implementation pattern and not the standard pattern. Had I said "this is how to implement `OrderBy`" then I would agree with your comment.

Comment: I see nothing in the OP indicating that it not implement `OrderBy` properly.  What about it indicates that you shouldn't provide an implementation that is at least a functional equivalent of the BCL version?