# How does Enumerable.OrderBy use keySelector

Tags: c#, linq

Using the proceeding code, I successfully managed to produce a collection of numbers and shuffle the elements' position in the array:

```
var randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                    .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid());
```

Everything functions fine but it's kind of thrown a spanner in my works when trying to understand `Enumerable.OrderBy`. Take the following code for example:

```
var pupils = new[] 
{ 
    new Person() { Name = "Alex", Age = 17 },
    new Person() { Name = "Jack", Age = 21 } 
};

var query = pupils.OrderBy(x => x.Age);
```

It's my understanding that I am passing the property I wish to sort by and I presume that LINQ will use `Comparer<T>.Default` to determine how to order the collection if no explicit `IComparer` is specified for the second overload. I really fail to see how any of this reasonable logic can be applied to shuffle the array in such a way. So how does LINQ let me shuffle an array like this?

Comment: I dont understand your question here. In your above example, assuming age is an int, `query` will contain the ordered list. So, your initial array is not sorted or shuffled.

Comment: I updated the post. I am talking about the first code sample.

Comment: Try Fisher-Yates shuffling in actual code though.. Faster..

Comment: @ryadavilli I updated the post. I'm talking about the first code sample.

Comment: @nawfal Thanks but this is not a speed critical environment.

Comment: The answer below by @Tilak covers it well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How does Enumerable.OrderBy use keySelector?

`Enumerable.OrderBy<T>` lazily returns - keySelector is not called directly.  The result is an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` that will perform the ordering when enumerated.

When enumerated, keySelector is called once for each element.  The order of the keys defines the new order of the elements.

Here's a nifty [sample implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13080592/8155).

---

> So how does LINQ let me shuffle an array like this?

```
var randomNumbers = Enumerable
  .Range(0, 100)
  .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid());
```

Guid.NewGuid is called for each element.  The call for the second element may generate a value higher or lower than the call for first element.

`randomNumbers` is an `IOrderedEnumerable<int>` that produces a different order each time it is enumerated.  KeySelector is called once per element each time `randomNumbers` is enumerated.

Answer (score 4):

You're pretty close to understanding how such shuffling works.. In your second case

```
pupils.OrderBy(x => x.Age);
```

the `Comparer<int>.Default` is used (the persons are sorted by their `Age`, simple).

In your first case, `Comparer<Guid>.Default` is used.

*Now how does that work?*.

Every time you do `Guid.NewGuid()` (presumably) a different/original/non duplicated `Guid` is produced. Now when you do

```
var randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid());
```

the numbers are sorted on the basis of the generated Guids.

*Now what are guids*?

They are 128 bit integers represented in hexadecimal form. Since 2^128 is such a large number the chances of generating two Guids are very rare/almost impossible. Since Guids exhibit some sort of randomness, the ordering will be random too.

*How are two Guids compared to enforce the ordering?*

You can confirm it based on a trivial experiment. Do:

```
var guids = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select((x, i) => 
    {
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        return new { Guid = guid, NumberRepresentation = new BigInteger(guid.ToByteArray()), OriginalIndex = i };
    }).ToArray();

var guidsOrderedByTheirNumberRepresentation = guids.OrderBy(x => x.NumberRepresentation).ToArray();
var guidsOrderedAsString = guids.OrderBy(x => x.Guid.ToString()).ToArray();

var randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).OrderBy(x => guids[x].Guid).ToArray();

//print randomNumbers.SequenceEqual(guidsOrderedByTheirNumberRepresentation.Select(x => x.OriginalIndex)) => false

//print randomNumbers.SequenceEqual(guidsOrderedAsString.Select(x => x.OriginalIndex)) => true
```

So `Comparer<Guid>.Default` is based on the string representation of the guid.

---

Aside:

You should use [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffling for speed. May be

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> lst)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = lst.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int j = rnd.Next(i + 1);
        yield return lst[j];
        lst[j] = lst[i];
    }
}
```

Or for conciseness, may be just (which can be still faster than Guid approach)

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> lst)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    return lst.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> So how does this work?

Following query uses `Comparer<Guid>.Default` for comparison.

```
  .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
```

Since every generated GUID is practically unique (as you are generating in the `OrderBy` clause itself), you are believing that you are getting random order (which is incorrect understanding).
If you run the query again you will again see (presumably) shuffled result as new set of GUIDs will be generated.

If you will use predefined GUIDs, you will see order.

Example `randomNumbers1` and `randomNumbers2` have same values in below.

```
var randomGuids = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select (x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();

var randomNumbers1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).OrderBy(x => randomGuids[x]);

var randomNumbers2 = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).OrderBy(x => randomGuids[x]);
```

---

> I really fail to see how any of this reasonable logic can be applied to shuffle the array in such a way.

You are able to shuffle because there is no order between elements (`GUID` in your example). If you use elements that have ordered, you will get ordered output instead of shuffled one.